# When I try to install ansible from source method I lose my ansible

Tags: ansible

I try to install ansible through the source method but I got a wall ...

I installed it by typing

```
 source ./hacking/env-setup
```

I got a `done` so I suppose it succeeds.

After I got

```
root@pc:~/devnet/ansible# ansible --version
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following line:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```